# How can i run my code in Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am new in codelaboratory and I am not knew how works. For example, I create a new file but when i try to run it appears this message: "We have received your request to access Colaboratory backends. We will notify you when Colaboratory is ready for you to use."

Answer (score 1):

Access to code execution currently requires signing up.

The message you received indicates that you have registered.

I'd expect to receive a notification within a few hours that your request has been approved.